# What is Statistics?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, philosophy

In Mathematics, what is Statistics? For myself I just want to know what Statistics mean in it's purest form? also I need a much simpler definition or explanation for kids aged 4-10. Need to explain probability to kids, so I have to explain Statistics first.

Comment: Statistics is all about quantifying uncertainty in events with a certain degree of belief with all of the information that is on hand. I usually play the 'Monthy Hall Problem' with people that don't have any knowledge in statistics. This usually helps a lot! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem . Using paradoxes like 'the birthday paradox' or 'the gambler fallacy', often helps!

Comment: @Matthew Daly you know, using the same word in the explanation which you are trying to define can be confusing to a kid... Thanks for the comment though...

Comment: Thanks @FromTheoryToPractice. So "quatifying uncertainity" means quantifying the unquantifiable, within acceptable limits...

Comment: uncertainty can be defined as 'that that we don't know'. So you want to quantify the amount you don't know about a specific event. This could be due to incomplete information, inherent stochasticity in the system, or other reasons. Edit: it's early in the morning here, so I confused statistics with probability theory (in the field where I work in, it often gets used interchangeable)

Comment: Educated guessing.

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice I think Uncertainity is something that you Cannot know...

Comment: @Ashish...well, if you look at the Monthy Hall Problem: in essence, the outcome is deterministic. But for the contestant, because he has limited information, the outcome is uncertain. Einstein once said: 'God doesn't play dice', meaning that uncertainty is just something we cannot observe and not something you cannot know.

Comment: @FromTheoryToPractice yes within math uncertainity is something we cannot Observe but otherwise uncertainity is something we cannot Know. IMHO

Comment: @Ashish Shukla yes, or something you just cannot know for certain

Comment: @WilliamElliot Hi Thanks. So can I say that our Mind aided by Math using formulas, allows us to make "educated guess" over much more data than our unaided mind alone? If that is so than can you please tell me how do logs and exponents help in it...

Comment: How old are the kids? Their age can vary quite a lot and from the sample I observed, what they can understand and what they enjoy is strongly related to their age.

Comment: This might be a better fit for matheducators.se.

Comment: @Taladris from 4 to 8, I am one of them. I was explaining probability vs. belief to them. They want to make a remote controlled drone and we live in a village in India. So from that explanation I wanted to make them also understand difference between Mind and Heart(Intuition), so I stumbled upon Statistics and wanted to know what it is...

Comment: One way to describe it is, "The study of how to make valid conclusions based on limited data." To be a bit more concrete, but slightly less general, you can say that a major goal of statistics is to make conclusions about a population based on a small sample from that population. For example, we might want to figure out what fraction of the population supports a particular political candidate, based on the results of a survey.

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Statistics is basically (lossy) data-compression ... Don't tell that to your kids, but it does show that it is effectively summarizing sets of data points in such a way that they become more meaningful to our feeble mind (if we were infinitely smart, there would be no need for statistics: we could just look at the data set and see everything that's there). If this is for young kids, I would illustrate it with something simple like taking an average: have them count how many times they hear/see [something] every day for several days, take that average, and say: "we're doing statistics, kids!"

Comment: Hey @gen-zreadytoperish I don't understand the problem. This is the kind of well meaning objection which doesn't add any value in terms of resolution of the question. Maybe you don't have anything to say but that does not mean others don't have either. Pleanty people commented and answered, and maybe I am not looking for a precise answer. I don't know WHAT to change that question to. One of my young students asked and it seemed legitimate question to me. I cannot even appeal don't like the way disagreements are handled at stackexchange...

Comment: @Bram28 Today I read your comment(Carefully) and realised that you are saying the exact same thing I have been shouting at people for so many years. Thank you. Our minds are tools which are equipped to handle a finite set of information, excluding both the extremes, meaning our minds cannot handle Zero or INFINITY. To say that I "Intellectually understand" Zero and Infinity, IS WRONG. We ALWAYS "INTUITIVELY UNDERSTAND" Zero and Infinity. Well this question has been meaningful in so many ways. Thanks... By the Way, today I am tackling/learning multiplication in school...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest context, a statistic (small 's') is a function whose input is a data set and whose output is some real number.  We then define Statistics (big 'S') to be the study of these types of functions.  (this is what one of the comments initially said)

Of course, we try to avoid any ounce of formality when introducing a topic, especially to children, so to them, I think a more appropriate definition (even if it's imprecise) would be:

"Statistics is the study of how to summarize large data sets and how meaningful those summaries are."

For instance, the mean, median, and mode provide numbers which summarize "where" the data generally is.  Likewise, the variance or standard deviation provide numbers which summarize how close together the data generally is.  We can even talk about much more complicated values that summarize a data set, but these are the ones that are most likely to be seen in the real world.

Comment: So would you say that a fairly small set of "what and how to" of summarization describes most datasets found in Nature? And where can I find a list of statistic(s) and what they say about a dataset?

Comment: Great answer, especially the distinction between semi-formal definition and children-friendly definition. What you defined is actually 'descriptive statistics'. Do you have similar definitions for 'inferential statistics'?

Comment: @Taladris I'm not a statistician by any means, but I'm pretty sure the definition I gave is broad enough to encompass both descriptive and inferential statistics (and maybe more...).  Feel free to correct me if I'm grossly inaccurate here, but afaik the main difference between the two at the level of theory is how they interpret the undefined terms "large" and "data set" --- with very divergent results --- and since I don't even try to define either, it's ambiguous enough to encompass both.  (That said, I do agree that my last paragraph is interpreted in the context of descriptive statistics.)

Comment: Hypothesis testing also gives us a summary of a data set and how meaningful that summary is, in the sense that a significance level is "meaningful." So I would say this covers more than just descriptive statistics.

Comment: "We can even talk about much more complicated values that summarize a data set, but these are the ones that are most likely to be seen in the real world." I would Love to have that kind of mastery over the subject... @BrianMoehring Thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 2):

To understand what statistics is, you need to contrast it with probability.

Probability deduces how likely events are based on certain assumptions. If I asked you how likely you were to get exactly two heads when tossing a coin five times, you'd probably assume each toss is independent, with a probability of $\frac12$ of giving heads.

Statistics is how we test such assumptions by looking at events that really happened. If all five tosses gave heads, that might not prove anything's amiss, since in theory it has a $1$ in $32$ chance. By "in theory", I mean on our assumptions, which in this context we call a null hypothesis. We might call the null hypothesis into question, however, if $70$ of $100$ tosses gave heads.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is the abstract science of numbers, quantity and space. Mathematics may be studied in its own right (pure mathematics), or as it is applied to other disciplines such as physics and engineering (applied mathematics).

Statistics is the science of collecting and analyzing numerical data in large quantities, especially for the purpose of inferring proportions as a whole from those in a representative sample. It can be considered as a branch of applied mathematics concerned with collecting, organizing, and interpreting data. The data are represented by means of graphs.

Mathematicians solve problems. Problems they work on range from pure mathematical problems to applied problems. Mathematicians try to find common features in seemingly distinct problems. That is, they look for patterns. They classify what behaviors can result from certain systems.

Statisticians develop techniques to overcome problems in data collection and analysis. They use statistical methods to collect and analyze data and to help solve real-world problems in business, engineering, healthcare and other fields.

${}$

Ref.: https://scse.d.umn.edu/about/departments-and-programs/mathematics-statistics-department/what-math

Comment: "Statistics is the science of collecting and analyzing data" without "numerical" would be more comprehensive. Certainly, the kids should be introduced to the categorical and numerical types of data first.

Comment: @farruhota I was able to make them understand what 1 is, so they know numerical data type. Categorical I will do as and when opportunity arises. Thanks

Comment: Apparently, you explained what $1$ is with objects like apple, pen, car, etc. So, you can have several kids have different objects (say, one has 4 apples, another has 3 pears, etc) and show their possessions by bar graph, so the graph is a summary (representation of the data, i.e. facts and figures).

Comment: Statistics is a branch of mathematics, and statisticians are mathematicians too, as they also find common features in seemingly distinct problems and look for patterns. Statisticians deal with problems concerning data, using mathematics to solve them.

Comment: Yes, @bing-nagata-smirnov, infact, it was mentioned in my discussion.